# Cant use MAMP when laravel installed?

Tags: laravel, mamp

I have MAMP installed which is fine. One of the project is Laravel. My laravel project is placed like this:

```
MAMP/htdocs/LaraBlog/laravel
```

but then i just want a normal PHP project on my mamp server aswell. I have placed it like this:

```
MAMP/htdocs/notes
```

But when i go to

http://localhost:8888/notes it tries to find a laravel route? i havent a artisan serve running. What is wrong?

Comment: But when i go to http://localhost:8888 it actually go to my laravel start site. Can i see if i have a php artisan running?

Answer (score 1):

Then you probably have only created one host that points to..

```
MAMP/htdocs/LaraBlog/laravel/public
```

If you have MAMP Pro you can just create another host like *larablog.dev* that points to..

```
MAMP/htdocs/LaraBlog/laravel/public
```

and for "normal" PHP work you can use *localhost*.

**If you do not have MAMP Pro open that file..**

```
MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

At the end of that file you can do something like that..

```
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/LaraBlog/laravel/public"
  ServerName larablog.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you need to update your hosts file.
Open you Terminal and run this command..

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

and put this at the end..

```
127.0.0.1 larablog.dev
```

Now restart MAMP and you can access *larablog.dev* for your Laravel application and *localhost* for the other things.